# App Inventor post JSON to server

Tags: app-inventor

I'm trying to post JSON data from App Inventor to server but error occurred and I don't know where the problem is.

I did it successfully with Scratch 2 and Firefox RESTClient. Both work fine, but not in App Inventor.

[image]

URL: https://api.myserver.com/v2/users/***

HEADER: Content-Type:application/json

BODY: {"in":true}

Answer (score 0):

Your text to post is no valid JSON format, you can check it here [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) ...
You might want to try `{"in": true}` instead...

Btw. what about additionally posting the error message you get...
You can get it in the Web2.GotText event...